# Entity Framework Core no duplicate entries with ErrorMessage

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

What is the best way to avoid duplicate entries with MVC-EFC and ErrorMessage return

Model Test.cs

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a Name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max 50 character")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Max 100 character")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I use a ApiController with "ErrorMessage" return.
For column "Name" i do not want duplicates and a ErrorMessage return like "Entry already available!"
What is the best way?

Comment: if you are looking to add something within the class, note that all the above validation are done on the client and web server, without hitting the db. Duplication check will need it to hit the db. I don't see how it can be done within a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement custom `ValidationAttribute`

1. Customer `ValidationAttribute`

   ```
   public class UniqueValidation : ValidationAttribute
   {
   private readonly string _errorMessage;
   public UniqueValidation(string ErrorMessage)
   {
       _errorMessage = ErrorMessage;
   }
   protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
   {
       if (validationContext != null && typeof(IName).IsAssignableFrom(validationContext.ObjectType))
       {
           ApplicationDbContext db = validationContext.GetService(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)) as ApplicationDbContext;
           IQueryable<IName> result = db.GetType().GetMethod("Set").MakeGenericMethod(validationContext.ObjectType).Invoke(db, null) as IQueryable<IName>;
           var v = result.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == ((IName)validationContext.ObjectInstance).Name);
           if (v != null)
           {
               return new ValidationResult(_errorMessage);
           }
       }
       return ValidationResult.Success;
   }
    }
   ```
2. Use

   ```
   public class File: IName
   {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [UniqueValidation("FileName is exist")]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [InverseProperty("Avatar")]
   public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
   }

   public interface IName
    {
   string Name { get; set; }
    }
   ```